# Passing two values with parentheses in a single argument function

Tags: c, gcc, operator-precedence

I got this question from a website asking to give the output of the code

```
void reverse(int i)
{
    if (i > 5)
        return ;
    printf("%d ", i);
    return reverse((i++, i));
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    reverse(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is `1 2 3 4 5`

but `reverse` function is called recursively passing two values within parantheses. How precedence and associativity working here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`,` in `(i++, i)` is a comma operator. It's operands evaluate from left to right. It evaluates `i++`, value of `i` get incremented and the value of the expression `i++` is discarded and then the incremented value is passed to the function. So, ultimately only a single argument is passed to the function `reverse`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not *two* values with extra parentheses, but *one* argument that contains a [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Answer (score 3):

According to [haccks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455888/haccks), here is a comma operator.

The expression:

```
(i++,  i)
```

First **expression1** is evaluated, then **expression2** is evaluated, and the **value of expression2 is returned** for the whole expression.

Answer (score 1):

Explaination:

```
void reverse(int i)
{
    if (i > 5)
       return ;
    printf("%d ", i);
    return reverse((i++, i)); // it's single arument that is (i++ , i)
 }
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    reverse(1);
    return 0;
 }
```

More explaination like

```
a = (1, 2, 3);
```

`(1,2,3)` is a single argument but what is assigned to a?

brackets are used so comma operator is executed first and we get the `a` assigned  as 3 
so statements before comma's are executed first and 3 is assigned

**In your case**
 `i++` is executed first and then  `i` is passed as argument